# Python: how would you interpret this code containing reset_index and shift methods

Tags: python, shift

How would you interpret this code?

```
variable_name = df[df.column_name.shift() != df.column_name].reset_index()
```

Comment: df[<expression>] means give me rows in df that satisfies this expression.  Then look for the meaning of shift() and you will see the answer to your question.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, this is called boolean masking

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                    'Col2': [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                    'Col3': [17, 27, 27, 37, 52]})
```

You see how Col3 has repeating value of 27 in it.
When you apply shift on Col3, the result is:

```
0     NaN
1    17.0
2    27.0
3    27.0
4    37.0
```

So when you apply boolean equivalence test on this you get:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
```

Then, you apply boolean masking on DF and voila the second 27 is gone. But your index is now out of order so you apply reset_index to your dataframe. This methods basically gets rid of repeating values in a series data but only spares the first one.